# Swipe Input fails when Reloading Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Application.LoadLevel("0");
```

to Reload the scene as soon the player fails and clicks on retry. But after the Level has been reloaded like this the swipe Input fails What can be the reason for this?

Swipe Code

```
void Update()
{
    foreach (Touch t in Input.touches)
    {
        switch (t.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                Initial = t.position;
                Swiped = false;
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                Direction = t.position - Initial;
                if (Direction.magnitude > 100.0f)
                {
                    Direction = Direction.normalized;
                    Swiped = true;
                }
                break;
        }
        if (Swiped && count == 0)
        {

            if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, Vector2.up) > Mathf.Sqrt(0.5f))
            {
                // Up
                BroadcastMessage("swipedUp", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, -1 * Vector2.up) > Mathf.Sqrt(0.5f))
            {
                // Down
                BroadcastMessage("swipedDown", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, Vector2.right) > Mathf.Sqrt(0.5f))
            {
                // Right
                BroadcastMessage("swipedRight", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
            else if (Vector2.Dot(Direction, -1 * Vector2.right) > Mathf.Sqrt(0.5f))
            {
                // Left
                BroadcastMessage("swipedLeft", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above Code Works great when I first start playing the game, but when I try to reload the same scene It fails.The Game has only one Scene.My Start Method

```
void Start()
{
    Swiped = false;
    paused = false;
    GameOver = false;
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your swipe code.

Comment: I know that the Awake() is being called since I see random objects Generated on screen which I wrote in the Awake() Method But the Swipe input is not working and How to attach with the debugger @Formic

Comment: Second Time Update() is being called but FixedUpdate() is not @Formic

Comment: I also removed the swipe inputs and coded key inputs like up,right,left, and down arrows but it still dowsnot work

Comment: @Formic Everthing is Checked and the Update() is being called but not the FixedUpdate()

Comment: @Formic I got it I modified TimeScale When the player fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are using static variables in your code. These will not be reset when you call Application.LoadLevel("0"); because they are not part of the objects.

Comment: The static variable was Time.timeScale, I set it to 0 when player fails